# JavaScript: remove event listener not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, debouncing, removeeventlistener

I'd like to remove event listeners using JavaScript but it seems not working... I've tried passing `debounce` as well as `showPopup` functions as arguments to `removeEventListener`.

```js
const elementToListenForScroll = document.querySelector('.howitworks__mainheading');
const distanceToTop = elementToListenForScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top;

function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
        args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

function showPopup() {
  const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if (currentScrollPosition > distanceToTop) {
    console.log('hey it works');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', debounce);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(showPopup));
```

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: sorry for that, didn't notice that :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be? `window.removeEventListener('scroll', showPopup);` The functions you pass in seem to differ.

Comment: think about to remove event scroll in the window... Sounds strange

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl seems like not, because addEventListener takes in the `debounce` function as an argument, as the debounce itself calls `showPopup` function.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón how would you implement that otherwise?

Comment: what is the needed for remove the scroll event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debounce(showPopup)` isn't same as just `debounce`.

`debounce(showPopup)` call executes code when `debounce` just reference to the function.

To be able to `removeEventListener` you need pass same function reference which you pass to the `addEventListener`.

Assign `debounce(showPopup)` to some variable and use it for event subscription/unsubscription.

Example:

```js
    const elementToListenForScroll = 
    document.querySelector('.howitworks__mainheading');
    const distanceToTop = elementToListenForScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    

    var realReference =  debounce(showPopup);
    function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
      var timeout;
      return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    }
    
    function showPopup() {
      const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      if(currentScrollPosition > distanceToTop) {
        console.log('hey it works');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', realReference);
      }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', realReference);
```

Answer (score 0):

**window.removeEventListener** expects the function registered in **window.addEventListener**. In our case, it's the function returned by debounce(showPopup). Save in a variable.

```
var debouncedShowPopup = debounce(showPopup);

function showPopup() {
  const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if(currentScrollPosition > distanceToTop) {
    console.log('hey it works');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', debouncedShowPopup);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedShowPopup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i made a simple example in jsfiddle, changing window for document, to access to the scroll event. 
Take a look, it seems show your `console.log('it works')`

[JSFiddle mirror of code below](https://jsfiddle.net/fqwhbr2n/)

```js
const elementToListenForScroll = document.querySelector('.howitworks__mainheading');
const distanceToTop = elementToListenForScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top;

console.log(distanceToTop, 'distanceToTop');

function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

function showPopup() {
  console.log('deboundece', window.scrollY, distanceToTop);
  const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if (currentScrollPosition > 100) {
    console.log('hey it works');
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', debounce);
  }
}
console.log(document);
document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(showPopup));
```

```css
.howitworks__mainheading {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="howitworks__mainheading">
  Any other way
</div>
```